# Dojo Dialog show image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-type, dojo

I'm trying use Dojo Dialog to show an image, but I have something wrong on my code behind or in my front end. I believe this is a problem of Content-type.

[image]

```
    public ActionResult GetUploadedFile(int FileUploadId)
    {
        var photos = new GenericRepository<FileUpload>().Find(x => x.FileUploadId == FileUploadId);
        if (photos.Any())
        {
            var photo = photos.First();
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
            return File(new WebImage(photo.Path).GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");
        }

        // Loading a default photo for realties that don't have a Photo
        return File(new WebImage(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Content/images/no-photo100x100.png")).GetBytes(), "image/png");
    }
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Could you post JS dojo dialog code at here?? Also please attach the HTML result code (with dojo dialog JS) which generated by ASP.net.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but is very hard get the code because this CMS hidden many things. But I solved using a append method on dojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code something like this,

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="showFileDialog" title="Show Files">
    <img src="<% Response.write( GetUploadedFile(1234) ) %>"/>
</div>
```

but for your cases, it should be like that

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="showFileDialog" title="Show Files">
    <img src="viewFile.aspx?file_id=1234"/>
</div>
```

Moreover, you can use data URI, here is the example code,

```
var image = new WebImage(@"~\images\myImage.jpg");
var base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(image.GetBytes());
....
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<% Response.write(base64string) %>" />
```

Referrence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme